# Boost library types

Tags: c++, boost

I understand the differences between header-only libraries, dynamically linked libraries (`.so` files which means shared object) and static libraries (`.a` like archives).

Anyway, what I don't understand completely: why are there Boost libraries that must be precompiled and linked dynamically (`.so` files), and libraries that can be used only with their headers? What's the reason behind the need to linked dynamically? Please, be as specific and detailed as possible. :)

Regards,
Zsolt

Comment: As far as I understand, it's impossible to use _any_ precompiled library without its headers. The same goes for `.a` static libs. You can use dynamic libraries to reduce (sometimes greatly) the size of the executable as these libs are distributed independently and may _already_ be installed on the clients' computers. So, you distribute just your program, but the users have to get the libs themselves when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a large extent, it's an optimization.  Here are some reasons why you'd put at least part of your library code into a separately-built library file (e.g. shared object) rather than only using headers:

1. You might require a global variable which needs to be stored somewhere--the easiest place to put it is in a compiled object of your own.
2. Clients of your library need to use it via an "foreign function interface" (FFI) which is typically based on `dlopen()` and therefore requires compiled code rather than headers (which many FFIs cannot read).
3. Your code is significant in size, perhaps containing one or more large functions.  Compiling this only once typically saves compilation time and executable size.
4. You wish to ship code which is not visible in source form, e.g. to stifle reverse engineering or outright theft of your code.